When I configured ntp time synchronization, some problems occurred
systemctl status ntp
● ntp.service - Network Time Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ntp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-06-17 18:45:33 CST; 15h ago
       Docs: man:ntpd(8)
    Process: 3507107 ExecStart=/usr/lib/ntp/ntp-systemd-wrapper (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 3507115 (ntpd)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 76806)
     Memory: 1.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/ntp.service
             └─3507115 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 129:136

6月 18 10:13:22 ubuntu ntpd[3507115]: receive: Unexpected origin timestamp 0xea1b6bc2.0199208b does not match aorg 0000000000.00000000 from server@10.104.62.39 xmt 0xea1b6ae3.fc01fc59
6月 18 10:13:22 ubuntu ntpd[3507115]: receive: Unexpected origin timestamp 0xea1b6bc2.0199208b does not match aorg 0000000000.00000000 from server@10.104.62.39 xmt 0xea1b6ae3.fbfcb776
6月 18 10:13:22 ubuntu ntpd[3507115]: receive: Unexpected origin timestamp 0xea1b6bc2.0199208b does not match aorg 0000000000.00000000 from server@10.104.62.39 xmt 0xea1b6ae3.fc01fc59
6月 18 10:14:27 ubuntu ntpd[3507115]: receive: Unexpected origin timestamp 0xea1b6c03.0198af4a does not match aorg 0000000000.00000000 from server@10.104.62.39 xmt 0xea1b6b24.fc112846
6月 18 10:14:27 ubuntu ntpd[3507115]: receive: Unexpected origin timestamp 0xea1b6c03.0198af4a does not match aorg 0000000000.00000000 from server@10.104.62.39 xmt 0xea1b6b24.fc0fee8a
6月 18 10:14:27 ubuntu ntpd[3507115]: receive: Unexpected origin timestamp 0xea1b6c03.0198af4a does not match aorg 0000000000.00000000 from server@10.104.62.39 xmt 0xea1b6b24.fc112846
6月 18 10:15:33 ubuntu ntpd[3507115]: receive: Unexpected origin timestamp 0xea1b6c45.019a0a1e does not match aorg 0000000000.00000000 from server@10.104.62.39 xmt 0xea1b6b66.fc281ba7
6月 18 10:15:33 ubuntu ntpd[3507115]: receive: Unexpected origin timestamp 0xea1b6c45.019a0a1e does not match aorg 0000000000.00000000 from server@10.104.62.39 xmt 0xea1b6b66.fc234076
6月 18 10:15:33 ubuntu ntpd[3507115]: receive: Unexpected origin timestamp 0xea1b6c45.019a0a1e does not match aorg 0000000000.00000000 from server@10.104.62.39 xmt 0xea1b6b66.fc281ba7
6月 18 10:16:38 ubuntu ntpd[3507115]: receive: Unexpected origin timestamp 0xea1b6c86.0199db9f does not match aorg 0000000000.00000000 from server@10.104.62.39 xmt 0xea1b6ba7.fc48db3b

Below is the content of my configuration file (/etc/ntp.cof):
cat /etc/ntp.conf | grep -v "#"

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

leapfile /usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list


statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable



server 10.104.62.39 prefer
server time.windows.com


restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited

restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

restrict source notrap nomodify noquery

restrict 10.26.22.0 mask 255.255.255.0
restrict 10.26.21.0 mask 255.255.255.0

I want to know what the error "ubuntu ntpd[3507115]: receive: Unexpected origin timestamp 0xea1b6c86.0199db9f does not match aorg 0000000000.00000000 from server@10.104.62.39 xmt 0xea1b6ba7.fc48db3b" is. It seems to cause my time synchronization to fail.

This machine has no external network and can only synchronize time with the machine at 10.104.62.39

maybe related to https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000018710
